# Android: Make phone ring after clicking Volume Key Pattern

Tags: android

android: I want phone to ring and display contact info (Like a real phone call). when the user clicks the volume up key 3 times, and holds on 3rd click. I want this to be possible even from lock screen. Is this possible?

Thanks!

I made that change, I am trying to run on my galaxy s6 right now and the app is crashing. It will run but as soon as it opens it crashes. 
here is the code

```
package example.org.getaway;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static int number_of_times_volume_button_pressed = 0;
final MediaPlayer iphonering = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iphone);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    final MediaPlayer iphonering = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iphone);
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){

        if(number_of_times_volume_button_pressed==3)
        {
            iphonering.start();
            number_of_times_volume_button_pressed=0;
        }else
        {
            number_of_times_volume_button_pressed++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //Do something
        if(number_of_times_volume_button_pressed==3)
        {
              //Do something
              number_of_times_volume_button_pressed=0;
        }else
        {
              number_of_times_volume_button_pressed++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

use above method. In the similar manner you can use  onKeyUp.

globally declare a `int number_of_times_volume_button_pressed=0`.

you can find whole project [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwZ3hknwHurYMDk4QkpxMHp6VFE&usp=sharing)

Comment: can you please post the error you are getting while running app.